# flutter - List Length is always 0?

Tags: flutter

i try to make Gridbiew with other class's list

-- Gridview part

```
GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: iLength,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: iRow, childAspectRatio: iSep.toDouble()*0.5, crossAxisSpacing: 5, mainAxisSpacing: 15),
      itemBuilder: (context, sec_index) {
        //setState(() {});
        return GridView.builder(
          itemCount: iSep,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: iSep,
              childAspectRatio: 0.5,
              crossAxisSpacing: 0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10),
          itemBuilder: (context, sep_index) {
            int index1 = sec_index + 1;
            int index2 = sep_index + 1;
            var inst = Note(Sec: index1, Sep: index2);
            AppValues().list_Note.add(inst);                       // this list. i added
            print("Length : " + AppValues().list_Note.length.toString()); // check
            //AppValues().list_Note.
            return inst;
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

-- Other class, has list

```
class AppValues {
  AppValues();

  int Grid_Row = 15;
  int NoteSepreated = 1;
  int NoteLength = 50;
  NScript SelectScript = NScript.none;

  double PlaySpeed = 1.0;
  double PlaySpeed_Default = 1.0;
  double PlaySpeed_Min = 0.0;
  double PlaySpeed_Max = 2.0;

  List<Note> list_Note = List.empty(growable: true);   // here
}
```

-- result print

Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Windows...
flutter: Length : 0
flutter: Length : 0
flutter: Length : 0
flutter: Length : 0
flutter: Length : 0
flutter: Length : 0
flutter: Length : 0
flutter: Length : 0
flutter: Length : 0
flutter: Length : 0
flutter: Length : 0
Reloaded 1 of 969 libraries in 238ms (compile: 23 ms, reload: 71 ms, reassemble: 92 ms).

i'm very embrassed.
what i happened ?
is It kind of setState() problem ?

i dnt know any other choice

Comment: can you include how & where you've define `iLength`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
i Forgot list class make singletone. XD

class AppValues {
  AppValues._const() {}
  static final AppValues _inst = AppValues._const();
  factory AppValues() {return _inst;}

  int Grid_Row = 15;
  int NoteSepreated = 1;
  int NoteLength = 50;
  NScript SelectScript = NScript.none;

  double PlaySpeed = 1.0;
  double PlaySpeed_Default = 1.0;
  double PlaySpeed_Min = 0.0;
  double PlaySpeed_Max = 2.0;

  List list_Note = List.empty(growable: true);
}
```